# Doctrine2 getRepository and the use operator

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, namespaces

I am trying to clean up a little bit of code and am having some trouble. I have a few entities that I am using over and over again in a routing file. For example:

`$categories = $em->getRepository('SixString\Entities\Category')->findAll();`

I would like to take advantage of the `use` operator. At the top of my file I have the following:

`use \SixString\Entities\Category;`

I have tried both of the following:

`$categories = $em->getRepository('Category')->findAll();` and

`$categories = $em->getRepository(Category)->findAll();`

though I am getting the following errors:

Class Category does not exist and could not be loaded

and

Undefined Constant Category

Is it possible to use this reference with the `getRepository` method?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just...

```
$category_temp = $em->getRepository('NameOfBundle:Category')->findAll();
```

Comment: I am using doctrine2 outside of Symfony2. I am assuming `'NameOfBundle'` is in reference to Symfony2